# Multiple conditions findFirst

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

i am using phalcon framework and i want to find the correct item in my db. So i use the FindFirst function like:

```
$existing_entry = Files::findFirst(
        [
            'conditions'  => 'name = :name AND uuid = :uuid:',
            'bind'        => [
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'uuid' => $data['uuid']
            ]
        ]
    );
```

but i get no result. If i search only for name or uuid it works.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Remove `:` from the end of `:uuid:`

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders in PHQL are surrounded by `:`, while in PDO they are only prefixed.

Problem is in your `:name` placeholder, try like this:

```
$existing_entry = Files::findFirst([
    'conditions'  => 'name = :name: AND uuid = :uuid:',
    'bind'        => [
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'uuid' => $data['uuid']
    ]
]);
```

Notice the `:name:`.